# Creating maplayer to show high chlorophyll and sst locations based on SMI Modis imagecollection using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to create a maplayer to show spots where both chlor_a and sst show high values in google earth engine

I've used this code bellow but instead generated a map showing the chlorophyll values ​​opposite to the temperature values. How do I generate a layer that represents locations with both variables with high values ​​and how do I define the range of variation?

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI')
              .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-01-31');


var chlorsst =
dataset.select(['chlor_a', 'sst']);
var chlorsstVis = {
min: 0.0,
max: 99,
};
Map.setCenter(-52.12, -46.13, 4);
Map.addLayer(chlorsst, chlorsstVis,
 'ChlorSst');
print(chlorsst)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RGB color mixing as a way to show spots where both `chlor_a` and `sst` show high values (or low, or somewhere in between). Basically, you are assigning one variable to the color red and the other to blue and then mixing them (green is set to zero contribution) as they relate to the position in their respective data ranges. Data range is important here - to determine a data range over which to assign color, I've used the 2nd and 98th percentile of a sample area of interest as the min and max, respectively. The range result for this examples is:

> chlor_a_p2: 0.33766245716791987
>   chlor_a_p98: 3.7276654363022668
>   sst_p2: 2.9413550213569164
>   sst_p98: 19.681007371662343

Red and blue color saturation are then mapped according to these ranges. Red represents `chlor_a` and blue represents `sst`

- Pure Black: `chlor_a` and `sst` are both near the min of their respective ranges
- Pure blue: `chlor_a` at min of its range and `sst` at max of its range
- Pure red: `chlor_a` at max of its range and `sst` at min of its range
- Magenta: `chlor_a` and `sst` are at equal positions in their respective ranges (the intensity of the magenta ).

There are of course other shades of color that can be produced with the many combinations of values that are produced by these data, but they major patterns of high and low are quite obvious.

[image]

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/22f91487b5f115f2ee6aa1588477b210)

```js
// Define a region of interest - will be used to determine data range.
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[-61.172734375000005, -41.60272876097877],
    [-61.172734375000005, -53.82304493739765],
    [-40.342656250000005, -53.82304493739765],
    [-40.342656250000005, -41.60272876097877]]], null, false);

// Import dataset.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI')
  // Filter dates.
  .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-01-31')
  // Mosaic all images in the collection (could use .mean() or .median())
  .mosaic()
  // Select only the two bands of interest.
  .select(['chlor_a', 'sst']);

// Calculate the range of 2nd to 98th percentile to bound data for visualization.
// Statistics are calculated only within the region of interest.
var range = dataset.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.percentile({
    percentiles: [2, 98],
    outputNames: ['p2', 'p98']}),
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 10000});
print('Value range:', range);

// Make a function that scales the data between the 2nd to 98th percentiles to
// the 8-bit range (0 to 255) for visualization.
function scaleVis(img, min, max) {
  min = ee.Image.constant(min);
  max = ee.Image.constant(max);
  return img
    .subtract(min)
    .divide(max.subtract(min))
    .multiply(255)
    .round()
    .toByte();
}

// Select and apply the visualization function to the 'chlor_a' data.
var chlor_a = dataset.select('chlor_a');
var chlor_aVis = scaleVis(
  chlor_a, range.get('chlor_a_p2'), range.get('chlor_a_p98'));

// Select and apply the visualization function to the 'sst' data.
var sst = dataset.select('sst');  
var sstVis = scaleVis(
  sst, range.get('sst_p2'), range.get('sst_p98'));

// Make a blank image with all values set at 0.
var blank = ee.Image.constant(0).toByte();

// Make an RGB visualization image, where red represents chlor_a,
// green is set to no representation (blank image), and blue represents
// sst.
var vis = ee.Image.rgb(chlor_aVis, blank, sstVis);

// Display the original data and the visualization data to the map.
// Use the Inspector tab and click to explorer actual values for different
// regions of color.
Map.setCenter(-52.12, -46.13, 4);
Map.addLayer(dataset, null, 'Dataset');
Map.addLayer(vis, null, 'Visualization');
```